# post route test failing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

```js
describe("POST /post methods", () => {
      it("should get /post ", (done) => {
            const testing = {
              name: "charanjit",
              content: "im posting",
              giph: ""

            };
            chai.request(server)
              .post("/posts")
              .send(testing)
              .expect({
                id: 4,
                ...testing
              }, done)
```

Server.js

```js
server.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
      const incomingRequest = req.body;
      if (isValidPost(incomingRequest)) {
        const post = {
          name: incomingRequest.name.toString(),
          content: incomingRequest.content.toString(),
          giph: incomingRequest.gif.toString(),

          date: new Date(),
          likes: 0,
          dislikes: 0,
          laughs: 0,
          comments: [],
          //id : database.length
        };
```

When I run the test I getTypeError:  `chai.request(...).post(...).send(...).expect is not a function`.

I tried following tutorial online and I keep getting error for testing post request, can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the `expect` inside the call.

According to [docs](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) the call should be:

```js
chai.request(app)
  .put('/user/me')
  .send({ password: '123', confirmPassword: '123' })
  .end(function (err, res) {
     expect(err).to.be.null;
     expect(res).to.have.status(200);
  });
```

So try something like:

```js
chai.request(server)
  .post("/posts")
  .send(testing)
  .end(function (err, res) {
    expect(...)
    done()
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, but now i'm getting an error which says "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: Is the same problem that in your other question? I can answer there. But if the problem related to this question has been resolved, mark as accepted is appreciated.